# python request.post raise unexpected eof while reading

Tags: python, django, request, openssl, pyopenssl

i was upgraded recent version pyopenssl package in django project
after that request.post raise eof while reading error

```
import requests
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'someheader': 'SOMEVALUE',
}
json_value = {
    'value1': 'value1',
    'value2': 'value2',
}
url = 'https://url.s.o/m/e/u/r/l/'
res = requests.post(url, json=json_value, headers=headers)
```

this code raise error
`[('SSL routines', '', 'unexpected eof while reading')]`

i use

```
python 3.6
Django==2.1.2
pyopenssl==22.0.0
requests==2.27.1
openssl==1.1.1f
```

how can i solve it?